# Is there a way to figure out when an address is created?

Tags: address

I'm doing some bitcoin address collections. If there are some meaningful letters in the address or if the address is created in a meaningful time to me, I will buy it.

How can I know when the address is created?

Comment: What do you mean by "I will buy it [the address]"?

Comment: @Chuck Batson I will pay him for sharing the privatekey,of course I will never use the address for transactions,that would be stupid.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [At what point is a new wallet known by the Bitcoin network?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/13225/5406)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addresses are not created, *per se*. They're simply a representation of a public key. So, you cannot know when an address is "created."

However, it is possible to know the first time an address is *used*.

Comment: Maybe it's more accurate to say that it is possible to know the first time a transaction that moves outputs from/to a specific address is broadcasted (by querying the mempool) and the first time the same transaction is included into one or more blocks (by parsing the blockchain), as a newly-generated address can be used by an offline-generated transaction but we'll never know it unless it is broadcasted to the network, which can take any arbitrary amount of time.