# Is there any central management of public and private key pairs in blockchain?

Tags: address, traceability, governance, identity

Is there any entity in the blockchain that maintains record and manages public/private key pairs of all the users?

Comment: related: [At what point is a new wallet known by the Bitcoin network?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/13225/5406)

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't.  Bitcoin has no central management of anything at all.

Public keys are pseudonymous and in general it may not be possible to identify the user to whom a public key belongs.  A private key is kept by the user who generated it, and typically is never revealed to anybody else.